# How to sum with the result of two classes in React.js

Tags: reactjs, class

I have to add two results from two classes :

```
 <Display1 years={yearsValue1} amount={amountValue1} />
 <Display2 years={yearsValue2} amount={amountValue2} />
```

The values displayed are :

```
 1. amount={amountValue1} => ValuesDisplay1b
 2. amount={amountValue2} => ValuesDisplay2b
```

I need to sum ligne 1 and 2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the contents of Display1 and Display2. You can use functions instead.

Comment: Could you not simply sum the 2 values like so; `amountValue1 + amountValue1`?

Comment: `amountValue1, amountValue1 `are input values,   `<Display />`  behaves as a function like here : [link](https://github.com/GavBaros/react-loan-calculator/blob/master/src/components/Display.js) I want to add the outputs to make a total like here:
`Output of <Display1 /> + output of <Display2 />`  @shaune